# Prolog - Convert a 'cons' term to a list

Tags: list, prolog

I'm looking to convert a Prolog term similar to this:

```
cons(a, cons(b, cons(c, cons(d, nil ))))
```

into a list:

```
[a, b, c, d]
```

I have a function to verify that `cons(a, cons(b, cons(c, cons(d, nil ))))`
is a proper list, as follows:

```
list(nil).

list(cons(_,X)):-
    list(X).
```

which yields,

```
?- list(cons(a, cons(b, cons(c, cons(d, nil ))))).
true.
```

Now, when I pass a term like, **`list(cons(a, cons(b, cons(c, cons(d, nil ))))).`**, and it's **true**, I want to then be able to convert it to a list. I can do all of the rest, I'm just stuck on the conversion from the term to a list.

Any assistance pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've tried a few different things, like this for example: 
    {create_list(cons(_,X), L):-
        append(_, L, L2),
        L = L2.}  Is that along the lines of what you were thinking?

Comment: I think it's just the formatting. There's an underscore in my code, but it didn't show up in the comment.

Comment: The canonical form of a list in Prolog happens to be `'.'(H, T)` where `H` is the head and `T` is the tail (or *rest*) of the list. The bracket notation `[...]` is just a syntactic "sugar".  So `'.'` is actually Prolog's version of `cons` since the real form of `[a,b,c,d]` is `'.'(a, '.'(b, '.'(c, '.'(d, []))))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be:

```
list(nil, []).
list(cons(A,X), [A|L]):-
    list(X,L).
```

Example:

```
?- list( cons(a, cons(b, cons(c, cons(d, nil )))), L).
L = [a, b, c, d].
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much for your time!